# Laravel 5 redirect page with dynamically added fields after validation fails

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

In my form I have a few fields, which can be dynamically added by the user.

I add the fields via JQuery (functions.js). At the moment I work without an array and I am using a hidden-field, where the number of fields is stored.

```
$("#weiterer_artikel").on("click", function(){
    //read the value of the hidden field
    $anzahl = $("#bestellanzahl").val();

    //$anzahl is a String
    $anzahl = parseInt($anzahl);
    $neueAnzahl = $anzahl+1;

    //HTML code for a new article
    $nummer = "<div class='formgroup'><label for='nummer-"+$neueAnzahl+"' class='col-sm-2 control-label' id='nr-"+$neueAnzahl+"'>Nr.</label>"+
    "<div class='col-sm-10'><input type='text' name='nummer-"+$neueAnzahl+"' value='"+$neueAnzahl+"' class='form-control' readonly></div></div>";
    $artikel = "<div class='formgroup'> <label for='artikel-"+$neueAnzahl+"' class='col-sm-2 control-label' id='artikel-"+$neueAnzahl+"'>Artikel</label>"+
    "<div class='col-sm-10'><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Artikelname' name='artikel-"+$neueAnzahl+"' required></div></div>";
    $artnr = "<div class='formgroup'> <label for='art-nr-"+$neueAnzahl+"' class='col-sm-2 control-label' id='art-nr-"+$neueAnzahl+"'>Art.Nr.</label>"+
    "<div class='col-sm-10'><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Artikelnummer' name='art-nr-"+$neueAnzahl+"'></div></div>";
    $stk = "<div class='formgroup'> <label for='anzahl-"+$neueAnzahl+"' class='col-sm-2 control-label' id='anzahl-"+$neueAnzahl+"' required>Stk.</label>"+
    "<div class='col-sm-10'><select class='form-control' id='anzahl-"+$neueAnzahl+"' name='anzahl-"+$neueAnzahl+"'>"+
    "<option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></div></div>";

    //add field
    $("#bestellung-"+$anzahl).after("<div id='bestellung-"+$neueAnzahl+"'>"+$nummer+$artikel+$artnr+$stk+"</div>");

    //write new field number in hidden field
    $("#bestellanzahl").val($neueAnzahl);


});
```

My problem is, that if I send the form (via POST) and the serverside validation (via Form Request) fails, all manually added fields are removed from my view.

Are there any ways to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use ajax to submit you form, or you can store your dynamically added html to cookie.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it with ajax :)